# How do I set my squads to part time?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How do I set my squads to part time?

I wish to have a squad of, say 9 dorfs, and then set it so that only 3 are active at any one time.

How would one go about this?

Thanks, Urists!

Comment: Last I checked (about a year ago, just before the latest big updates), squads could only have a squad-wide schedule. If you needed more fine-tuned behavior, then you'd want to create smaller squads.

Comment: I'm thinking the same.  Three squads of three, each set to train/patrol/whatever a third of the time.  But I haven't played in so long I don't know if there's now a better way.

Comment: Ok, I was afraid that might be the case. Thanks chaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible.

Go to the screen that allows you to edit the squad schedule. 
[**m**ilitary then **s**chedule]
[image]

Select the squad you want. 
[Using **left** and **right** arrows]

Select the month.
[**Up** and **down** arrows]

Press the "tab" key to select a month.

Use **e** to edit orders.
**o** to set them.

When editing/setting orders you can use [**+** and **-**] to change how many Dwarves will follow that order at once. Change it to 3. (You can also set preferred Dwarves here who will be selected first to do the order.)

Press [**shift + enter**] to save the order for that month.

Use [**c** then **p**] to copy then paste the orders to other months. (Remember to give them months off.)

[Source](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Scheduling#Inactive_.2F_no_order)

Comment: Thanks Urist McLaiseran. I since figured this out but forgot to report back. Your answer is correct though, so thanks!